# How can I force www, remove trailing slash, force non-ssl and remove the .php extension using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I force www, remove trailing slash, force non-ssl and remove the .php extension using .htaccess?

I've tried a lot of things but I'm getting 500 internal server error a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code that you tried?

Comment: There are a billion similar questions. Do a search first.

Comment: Nothing else I have tried from previous questions worked. This is why I'm raising it again.

Answer (score 1):

Force www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Remove trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Force HTTP:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

About removing the php extension, i'm not completely sure, but you could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

However, this may fail for directories. But since i'm no longer using apache, i can just guess and not test it.

---

So, a combined solution could look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If I go to example.dev/about, it redirects me to www.example.dev/Users/James/Sites/example/about which isn't right at all

Comment: That's what i meant. I'll try to check and fix that.